# Segmentation Fault, program works fine

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault

I'm implementing the Prim's Algorithm for Minimum Spanning Tree Problem. Program Just works fine and I get the desired output but I received a *Segmentation Fault* in the End. I checked my program for errors but the program is fine.

Here's **Source Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#define INF 1000000
#define N 5

using namespace std;

class Graph
{
    int V;
    int adj[][N];

    public:
        Graph(int,int mat[][N]);
        void primsMST();
};

Graph::Graph(int v, int mat[][N])
{
   this->V = v;
   for(int i=0; i<v; i++)
   {
       for(int j=0; j<v; j++)
           adj[i][j] = mat[i][j];
   }
}

void Graph::primsMST()
{
    int i, j;

    int key[V];     // Key Value which is used to pick minimum weight vertex
    int parent[V];  // To store Tree
    bool mstSet[V];  // Mark Vertex included in MST

    // Initialize Key Values to infinite and mstSet to false
    for(i=0; i<V; i++)
    {
        key[i]=INF;
        mstSet[i] = false;
    }

    // Initialize initial vertex
    key[0] = 0;
    parent[0] = -1;

    int minm, min_i;
    for(int k=0; k<V-1; k++)
    {
        // Get min Key from all vertices
        minm = INF;
        for(i=0; i<V; i++) {
            if(!mstSet[i] && key[i]<minm)
            {
                minm = key[i];
                min_i = i;
            }
        }

        // Include min key vertex in MST
        mstSet[min_i] = true;

        // Update key values of vertices adjacent to min vertex
        for(j=0; j<V; j++)
        {
            if( adj[min_i][j] && !mstSet[j] && adj[min_i][j] < key[j])
            {
                key[j] = adj[min_i][j];
                parent[j] = min_i;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<V; i++)
        cout<<i<<", "<<key[i]<<", "<<parent[i]<<endl;

    // Print Minimum spanning Tree
    cout<<"Edge\tWeight"<<endl;
    for(i=1; i<V; i++)
        cout<<i<<"--"<<parent[i]<<"\t"<<adj[i][parent[i]]<<endl;

    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{

    int adjmat[][N] =  {{0, 2, 0, 6, 0},
                      {2, 0, 3, 8, 5},
                      {0, 3, 0, 0, 7},
                      {6, 8, 0, 0, 9},
                      {0, 5, 7, 9, 0},
                     };

    Graph g(N, adjmat);

    g.primsMST();

    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Program is compiled using `gcc version 4.7.2`.
When I run this program I got the desired output for the Graph but a Segmentation fault occurs in the end.

```
$ ./primsMST
0, 0, -1
1, 2, 0
2, 3, 1
3, 6, 0
4, 5, 1
Edge    Weight
1--0    2
2--1    3
3--0    6
4--1    5

Segmentation fault
```

Here's the debugging output using **gdb**

```
$ gdb primsMST
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/abhishek/myPrograms/geeksforgeeks/graphs/primsMST...done.
(gdb) set logging on
Copying output to gdb.txt.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/abhishek/myPrograms/geeksforgeeks/graphs/primsMST 
0, 0, -1
1, 2, 0
2, 3, 1
3, 6, 0
4, 5, 1
Edge    Weight
1--0    2
2--1    3
3--0    6
4--1    5



Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000002 in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000000000000002 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000800000003 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000005 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000003 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000700000000 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000800000006 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) quit
```

**Can anyone explain why I'm getting this Error?**

Comment: valgrind may be of great use.

Comment: I don't know how to use valgrind.

Comment: Just compile with debug symbols then run `valgrind yourProgram`. Valgrind will copiously signal anything wrong :p

Comment: Funny, I don't see where exactly you're initializing `adj` to the correct dimensions.

Comment: @barakmanos `adj` is initialized in the Constructor `Graph::Graph` with the values from parameter `mat`. If it wasn't initialized how come the output is correct?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia _'If it wasn't initialized how come the output is correct?'_ Because you've been hit by undefined behavior.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok what do you suggest? What should I change?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia _'Ok what do you suggest?'_ Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj;` instead of `int adj[][N];`

Comment: You should use the flag `-g` while compiling for debugging, then gdb will provide much more detailed informations about the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t allocate memory for the  rows of the ´adj´ matrix member of the of the graph class. This is teh most likely reason of the crash.
This may help: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) may help.

My understanding is the program runs by chance/because the the adj array is small.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, I never specified the `row` dimension of `adj` which created the problem. But I think I did that because I read that in 2D array declaration `row` dimension can be skipped if the value is initialized in the declaration itself. I'm accepting this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be cause by the incorrect accesses to the stack allocated arrays (adjmat and/or Graph::adj). Since these arrays are allocated on stack, incorrect accesses might corrupt other data, stored there (like function return address or other variables), which can cause segmentation fault when the destructors are called or when invalid return address is used.

Comment: The row arays of the adj matrix ara not allocated at all. Only the column array of pointers to rows is on stack.

Comment: Thanks, Got the problem now. Since I was not declaring `row` dimension in adj. Most likely it overwrote the stack frame and thus segmentation fault occurred.